# How to invoke Service class from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am developing an application to monitor network details..... for this i am using BrocastReceiver and service components... My BroadcastReceiver gets instantiated on device start-up and invokes Service class...

In the Service class i am fetching NetworkInfo, Signalstrength, Latitude, longitude and accuracy and storing these details in to the database...

My problem is :- I am able to create the Database but the values are not getting saved in the DB...

My BroadcastReceiver class is :-

```
public class NetworkInfoListner extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PendingIntent service = null; 
        Intent intentForService = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NetworkInfoService.class);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        if (service == null) {
            service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                    intentForService,    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, service);

    }
}
```

My Service Class:-

```
public class NetworkInfoService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    private String strNetworkInfo;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double accuracy;
    private int intSignalStrength;
    private NetworkDetailsVO networkDetailsVO = new NetworkDetailsVO();
    private NetworkInfoDatabaseHelper networkInfoDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
            String networkState = getNetworkStateString(networkInfo.getState());
            String stateString = networkInfo.toString().replace(',', '\n');
            strNetworkInfo = String.format("Network Type: %s\n Network State: %s\n\n %s",
                    networkInfo.getTypeName(),networkState,stateString);
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10f, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 300f, this);

        telephonyManager.listen(new SignalStrengthDetector(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        networkDetailsVO.setNetworkInfo(strNetworkInfo);
        networkDetailsVO.setPhoneNumber(telephonyManager.getLine1Number());
        networkDetailsVO.setOperatorName(telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName());
        networkDetailsVO.setSignalStrength(String.valueOf(intSignalStrength));
        networkDetailsVO.setLongitude(longitude);
        networkDetailsVO.setLatitude(latitude);
        networkDetailsVO.setAccuracy(accuracy);


        networkInfoDatabaseHelper = new NetworkInfoDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        networkInfoDatabaseHelper.saveRecord(networkDetailsVO);


    }

    private String getNetworkStateString(NetworkInfo.State state){

        String stateString = "unknown";

        switch(state)
        {
        case CONNECTED: 
            stateString = "connected";             
            break;

        case CONNECTING:        
            stateString = "connecting";    
            break;

        case DISCONNECTED:      
            stateString = "disconnected";  
            break;

        case DISCONNECTING:     
            stateString = "disconnecting";  
            break;

        case SUSPENDED:         
            stateString = "suspended";              
            break;

        default: 
            stateString = "unknown";     

            break;

        }

        return stateString;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();

    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String string) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10f, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {


    }


    private class SignalStrengthDetector extends PhoneStateListener{

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            intSignalStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        }

    }




}
```

My Manifest file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.networkinfodemo_v_03"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.networkinfodemo_v_03.activity.NetworkInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.pervazive.networkinfodemo_v_03.activity.service.NetworkInfoService" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.networkinfodemo_v_03.activity.broadcastreceiver.NetworkInfoListner" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIG_STR" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Helper class Code:-

```
public class NetworkInfoDatabaseHelper {


    private NetworkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper networkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "networkInfo.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "networkinfo";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; 
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NETWORK_INFO = "networkInfo";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER = "phonenumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPERATOR_NAME = "operatorname";
    public static final String COLUMN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH = "signalstrength";
    public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCURACY = "accuracy";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";





    public NetworkInfoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        networkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper = new NetworkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = networkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    private class NetworkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public NetworkInfoDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + COLUMN_NETWORK_INFO + " TEXT, "
                    + COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT, "
                    + COLUMN_OPERATOR_NAME + " TEXT, "
                    + COLUMN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH + " TEXT, "
                    + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " REAL, "
                    + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " REAL, "
                    + COLUMN_ACCURACY + " REAL, "
                    + COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT ) ");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }

    }



public void saveRecord(NetworkDetailsVO networkDetailsVO){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NETWORK_INFO, networkDetailsVO.getNetworkInfo());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER, networkDetailsVO.getPhoneNumber());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_OPERATOR_NAME, networkDetailsVO.getOperatorName());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH, networkDetailsVO.getSignalStrength());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LATITUDE, networkDetailsVO.getLongitude());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LONGITUDE, networkDetailsVO.getLatitude());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ACCURACY, networkDetailsVO.getDateTime());
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME, networkDetailsVO.getDateTime());


        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getRecord(){

        return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }
```

please let me know what is the error

Comment: you are scheduling an alarm in your `onReceive` ... I don't get it.

Comment: Hi Ovidiu Latcu, yes i have scheduled an Alaram in onReceive to invoke the service class after every minute.... i.e i am invoking the service class from broadcast receiver after every minute to monitor the network status... and i am storing the result into the database..(by invoking networkInfoDatabaseHelper.saveRecord(networkDetailsVO) method).

but unfortunately noting is getting saved into the database... i do not know the reason... :-(

Comment: Post the code of your ` networkInfoDatabaseHelper.saveRecord(...);` method of your helper class.

Comment: Hi Girishu, 
 i have attached the DatabaseHelper class code...

Comment: do you get any errors in the logcat?

Comment: The code is working fine.... i have removed this line from my service class

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 300f, this);

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar:

```
public class VoiceLaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {     
        Intent service = new Intent(ctx, VoiceLaunchService.class);
        ctx.startService(service);
        }
    }
```